# Inconsistent sorting results

Tags: sorting, collation, oracle

I am trying to use `collate binary_ci` in `order by` and I got inconsistent results from two queries. I expect those two results are supposed to be the same.

first query:

```
select column_value name,
       nlssort (column_value collate binary_ci) as sort_value
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','a','B','b','ä'))
order by name collate binary_ci;
```

result:

| name | sort_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6100 |
| a | 6100 |
| B | 6200 |
| b | 6200 |
| ä | C3A400 |

second query:

```
select column_value name,
       nlssort (column_value collate binary_ci) as sort_value
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','a','ä','B','b'))
order by name collate binary_ci;
```

result:

| name | sort_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6100 |
| a | 6100 |
| b | 6200 |
| B | 6200 |
| ä | C3A400 |

The only difference is where `ä` is. I expect the same result as first query no matter how these 5 letters ordered.

And my NLS settings:

| PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NLS_LANGUAGE | ENGLISH |
| NLS_TERRITORY | DENMARK |
| NLS_CURRENCY | kr |
| NLS_ISO_CURRENCY | DENMARK |
| NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS |  |
| NLS_CALENDAR | GREGORIAN |
| NLS_DATE_FORMAT | RR |
| NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE | ENGLISH |
| NLS_SORT | BINARY |
| NLS_TIME_FORMAT | HH24 |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT | RR |
| NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT | HH24 |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT | RR |
| NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY | € |
| NLS_COMP | BINARY |
| NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS | BYTE |
| NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP | FALSE |

Oracle version: Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.18.0.0.0

Any idea of why it behave like this and how can I make the result consistent?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a case-insensitive sort (via `binary_ci`), so the sort value for 'b' and 'B' is the same (6200), therefore the result is indeterminate. You can't say that one of your results is correct and the other incorrect. It's essentially doing what you asked it to. You would need some other criteria to make the result determinate, even for one of the queries (in theory anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort is non-deterministic.

With the `binary_ci`, 'a' and 'A' have the same sort code, so the database is free to return these in either order. Same applies to 'b' and 'B'.

If you want to guarantee the two queries return the rows in the same order, you need to order by unique values.

Assuming you case-insensitive sorting first, you can do this by adding the (uncollated) name to the end of the `order by`

```
select column_value name,
       nlssort (column_value collate binary_ci) as sort_value
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','a','B','b','ä'))
order by name collate binary_ci, name;

NAME    SORT_VALUE    
A       6100          
a       6100          
B       6200          
b       6200          
ä       C3A400  

select column_value name,
       nlssort (column_value collate binary_ci) as sort_value
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','a','ä','B','b'))
order by name collate binary_ci, name;

NAME    SORT_VALUE    
A       6100          
a       6100          
B       6200          
b       6200          
ä       C3A400
```